# Replace function in Sql getting duplicate of strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't seem to figure this problem out.

I want to replace `Face` with `Face book` but I keep getting `Face book book`.

Why is it doing that?

Here is my query:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE company
SET company = REPLACE(delivery_team, 'Face', 'Face book')
```

Comment: Do you already have 'Face book' as a string in any of the rows?

Comment: @Samir yes I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `WHERE` clause to filter out strings that already have 'Face book'

```
UPDATE company
SET company = REPLACE(company, 'Face', 'Face book')
WHERE company NOT LIKE '%Face book%';
```

If `company` column has only the valid company names and no other text in it, then the same thing can be achieved by a more optimized query as below,

```
UPDATE company
SET company = 'Face book'
WHERE company = 'Face';
```

As a side note, the correct company name is 'Facebook' ( without a space ).